# My tkinter code would crash often, how would I make it more efficient and shorter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

How can I make this code more efficient, shorter, and less repetitive?

**The first issue is these repetitive labels:** I'm not sure how to make these shorter.

```
label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()

label2 = tk.Label(root)
label2.pack()

label3 = tk.Label(root)
label3.pack()

label4 = tk.Label(root)
label4.pack()

label5 = tk.Label(root)
label5.pack()

label6 = tk.Label(root)
label6.pack()
```

**The labels above are used for the 'clear function' and 'outcome function':**

```
def clear_widget():
    widget = label
    widget2 = label2
    widget3 = label3
    widget4 = label4
    widget5 = label5
    widget6 = label6
    widget['text'] = ""
    widget2['text'] = ""
    widget3['text'] = ""
    widget4['text'] = ""
    widget5['text'] = ""
    widget6['text'] = ""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Clear", command=clear_widget)
    button.pack()
```

**This is the Rolls function:** It is used to roll a specific amount of times, using the percent given to determine the outcome of that roll.

```
def outcome():
    answer = int(Percent.get().strip())
    rolls = int(rollAmount.get().strip())
    k = c = c3 = c4 = c5 = c6 = 0 
#1 Roll
    while True:
        b = random.randrange(1,100)
        new = 100 - answer

        if b <= new:
            label['text'] = "Fail."
            k = k+1
        if b >= new:
            label['text'] = "Success!"
            k = k+1

        if k == rolls:
            break
#2 Rolls    
    if rolls == 2:
        while True:
            b2 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new2 = 100 - answer

            if b2 <= new2:
                label2['text'] = "Fail."
                c = c+1
            if b2 >= new2:
                label2['text'] = "Success!"
                c = c+1

            if c == rolls:
                break
#3 Rolls
    if rolls ==3:
        while True:
            b2 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new2 = 100 - answer

            if b2 <= new2:
                label2['text'] = "Fail."
                c = c+1
            if b2 >= new2:
                label2['text'] = "Success!"
                c = c+1

            if c == rolls:
                break

        while True:
            b3 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new3 = 100 - answer

            if b3 <= new3:
                label3['text'] = "Fail."
                c3 = c3+1
            if b3 >= new3:
                label3['text'] = "Success!"
                c3 = c3+1

            if c3 == rolls:
                break
#4 Rolls
    if rolls == 4:
        while True:
            b2 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new2 = 100 - answer

            if b2 <= new2:
                label2['text'] = "Fail."
                c = c+1
            if b2 >= new2:
                label2['text'] = "Success!"
                c = c+1

            if c == rolls:
                break

        while True:
            b3 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new3 = 100 - answer

            if b3 <= new3:
                label3['text'] = "Fail."
                c3 = c3+1
            if b3 >= new3:
                label3['text'] = "Success!"
                c3 = c3+1

            if c3 == rolls:
                break

        while True:
            b4 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new4 = 100 - answer

            if b4 <= new4:
                label4['text'] = "Fail."
                c4 = c4+1
            if b4 >= new4:
                label4['text'] = "Success!"
                c4 = c4+1

            if c4 == rolls:
                break
            
#5 Rolls
    if rolls == 5:
        while True:
            b2 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new2 = 100 - answer

            if b2 <= new2:
                label2['text'] = "Fail."
                c = c+1
            if b2 >= new2:
                label2['text'] = "Success!"
                c = c+1

            if c == rolls:
                break

        while True:
            b3 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new3 = 100 - answer

            if b3 <= new3:
                label3['text'] = "Fail."
                c3 = c3+1
            if b3 >= new3:
                label3['text'] = "Success!"
                c3 = c3+1

            if c3 == rolls:
                break

        while True:
            b4 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new4 = 100 - answer

            if b4 <= new4:
                label4['text'] = "Fail."
                c4 = c4+1
            if b4 >= new4:
                label4['text'] = "Success!"
                c4 = c4+1

            if c4 == rolls:
                break

        while True:
            b5 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new5 = 100 - answer

            if b5 <= new5:
                label5['text'] = "Fail."
                c5 = c5+1
            if b5 >= new5:
                label5['text'] = "Success!"
                c5 = c5+1

            if c5 == rolls:
                break

#6 Rolls
    if rolls == 6:
        while True:
            b2 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new2 = 100 - answer

            if b2 <= new2:
                label2['text'] = "Fail."
                c = c+1
            if b2 >= new2:
                label2['text'] = "Success!"
                c = c+1

            if c == rolls:
                break

        while True:
            b3 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new3 = 100 - answer

            if b3 <= new3:
                label3['text'] = "Fail."
                c3 = c3+1
            if b3 >= new3:
                label3['text'] = "Success!"
                c3 = c3+1

            if c3 == rolls:
                break

        while True:
            b4 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new4 = 100 - answer

            if b4 <= new4:
                label4['text'] = "Fail."
                c4 = c4+1
            if b4 >= new4:
                label4['text'] = "Success!"
                c4 = c4+1

            if c4 == rolls:
                break

        while True:
            b5 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new5 = 100 - answer

            if b5 <= new5:
                label5['text'] = "Fail."
                c5 = c5+1
            if b5 >= new5:
                label5['text'] = "Success!"
                c5 = c5+1

            if c5 == rolls:
                break

        while True:
            b6 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new6 = 100 - answer

            if b6 <= new6:
                label6['text'] = "Fail."
                c6 = c6+1
            if b6 >= new6:
                label6['text'] = "Success!"
                c6 = c6+1

            if c6 == rolls:
                break
```

**Entire Code**

```
import random
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Try code")

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()

Percent = tk.Entry(root)
Percent.pack()

percentLabel = tk.Label(root, text ="What is the percent of success?")
percentLabel.pack()

rollAmount = tk.Entry(root)
rollAmount.pack()

percentLabel = tk.Label(root, text ="How many rolls are you throwing?")
percentLabel.pack()

label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()

label2 = tk.Label(root)
label2.pack()

label3 = tk.Label(root)
label3.pack()

label4 = tk.Label(root)
label4.pack()

label5 = tk.Label(root)
label5.pack()

label6 = tk.Label(root)
label6.pack()

def outcome():
    answer = int(Percent.get().strip())
    rolls = int(rollAmount.get().strip())
    k = c = c3 = c4 = c5 = c6 = 0 
#1 Roll
    while True:
        b = random.randrange(1,100)
        new = 100 - answer

        if b <= new:
            label['text'] = "Fail."
            k = k+1
        if b >= new:
            label['text'] = "Success!"
            k = k+1

        if k == rolls:
            break
#2 Rolls    
    if rolls == 2:
        while True:
            b2 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new2 = 100 - answer

            if b2 <= new2:
                label2['text'] = "Fail."
                c = c+1
            if b2 >= new2:
                label2['text'] = "Success!"
                c = c+1

            if c == rolls:
                break
#3 Rolls
    if rolls ==3:
        while True:
            b2 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new2 = 100 - answer

            if b2 <= new2:
                label2['text'] = "Fail."
                c = c+1
            if b2 >= new2:
                label2['text'] = "Success!"
                c = c+1

            if c == rolls:
                break

        while True:
            b3 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new3 = 100 - answer

            if b3 <= new3:
                label3['text'] = "Fail."
                c3 = c3+1
            if b3 >= new3:
                label3['text'] = "Success!"
                c3 = c3+1

            if c3 == rolls:
                break
#4 Rolls
    if rolls == 4:
        while True:
            b2 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new2 = 100 - answer

            if b2 <= new2:
                label2['text'] = "Fail."
                c = c+1
            if b2 >= new2:
                label2['text'] = "Success!"
                c = c+1

            if c == rolls:
                break

        while True:
            b3 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new3 = 100 - answer

            if b3 <= new3:
                label3['text'] = "Fail."
                c3 = c3+1
            if b3 >= new3:
                label3['text'] = "Success!"
                c3 = c3+1

            if c3 == rolls:
                break

        while True:
            b4 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new4 = 100 - answer

            if b4 <= new4:
                label4['text'] = "Fail."
                c4 = c4+1
            if b4 >= new4:
                label4['text'] = "Success!"
                c4 = c4+1

            if c4 == rolls:
                break
            
#5 Rolls
    if rolls == 5:
        while True:
            b2 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new2 = 100 - answer

            if b2 <= new2:
                label2['text'] = "Fail."
                c = c+1
            if b2 >= new2:
                label2['text'] = "Success!"
                c = c+1

            if c == rolls:
                break

        while True:
            b3 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new3 = 100 - answer

            if b3 <= new3:
                label3['text'] = "Fail."
                c3 = c3+1
            if b3 >= new3:
                label3['text'] = "Success!"
                c3 = c3+1

            if c3 == rolls:
                break

        while True:
            b4 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new4 = 100 - answer

            if b4 <= new4:
                label4['text'] = "Fail."
                c4 = c4+1
            if b4 >= new4:
                label4['text'] = "Success!"
                c4 = c4+1

            if c4 == rolls:
                break

        while True:
            b5 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new5 = 100 - answer

            if b5 <= new5:
                label5['text'] = "Fail."
                c5 = c5+1
            if b5 >= new5:
                label5['text'] = "Success!"
                c5 = c5+1

            if c5 == rolls:
                break

#6 Rolls
    if rolls == 6:
        while True:
            b2 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new2 = 100 - answer

            if b2 <= new2:
                label2['text'] = "Fail."
                c = c+1
            if b2 >= new2:
                label2['text'] = "Success!"
                c = c+1

            if c == rolls:
                break

        while True:
            b3 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new3 = 100 - answer

            if b3 <= new3:
                label3['text'] = "Fail."
                c3 = c3+1
            if b3 >= new3:
                label3['text'] = "Success!"
                c3 = c3+1

            if c3 == rolls:
                break

        while True:
            b4 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new4 = 100 - answer

            if b4 <= new4:
                label4['text'] = "Fail."
                c4 = c4+1
            if b4 >= new4:
                label4['text'] = "Success!"
                c4 = c4+1

            if c4 == rolls:
                break

        while True:
            b5 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new5 = 100 - answer

            if b5 <= new5:
                label5['text'] = "Fail."
                c5 = c5+1
            if b5 >= new5:
                label5['text'] = "Success!"
                c5 = c5+1

            if c5 == rolls:
                break

        while True:
            b6 = random.randrange(1,100)
            new6 = 100 - answer

            if b6 <= new6:
                label6['text'] = "Fail."
                c6 = c6+1
            if b6 >= new6:
                label6['text'] = "Success!"
                c6 = c6+1

            if c6 == rolls:
                break            
def clear_widget():
    widget = label
    widget2 = label2
    widget3 = label3
    widget4 = label4
    widget5 = label5
    widget6 = label6
    widget['text'] = ""
    widget2['text'] = ""
    widget3['text'] = ""
    widget4['text'] = ""
    widget5['text'] = ""
    widget6['text'] = ""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Clear", command=clear_widget)
    button.pack()


button1 = tk.Button(text='Get Num', command=outcome)
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The reason why app crashes is not because of lots of labels, it is your `while` loop.

Comment: To make your code shorter, you could put the labels in a list and create them / configure them in for loops

Comment: @CoolCloud I played around with the code and it turns out my while loops were messing it up. it seems they were being repeated unnecessarily.

Comment: Use `root.after()`.

Answer (score 0):

The labels can be created using a for loop. I've created a list called `result_labels` and then used a for loop to create a label and add it to the list so I can use it later on.

```
result_labels = []
for x in range(6):
    label = tk.Label(root)
    label.pack()
    result_labels.append(label)
```

The outcome function can be reduced in size considerably using a for loop. It repeats the code as many times as the user inputs rolls. It then uses the `result_labels` created earlier to display the outcome.

```
def outcome():
    answer = int(Percent.get().strip())
    rolls = int(rollAmount.get().strip())
    for x in range(rolls):
        b = random.randrange(1,100)
        new = 100 - answer
        if b <= new:
            result_labels[x]["text"] = "Fail."
        if b >= new:
            result_labels[x]["text"] = "Success!"
```

Finally, `clear_widget` can be simplified by using a for loop and setting the text value for each item in `result_labels` to an empty string.

```
def clear_widget():
    for x in result_labels:
        x["text"] = ""
```